# Church-Turing Thesis and the human brain

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, computation, turing, philosophy-of-computer-science, computability-theory

A question on my homework: Imagine that scientists discover that the behavior of the brain can be completely described by some mathematical function. Given the Church–Turing Thesis, would this discovery entail that the behavior of the brain can be simulated by a Turing Machine?

My idea: not necessarily, because the human brain can be modeled by a Turing-uncomputable function. However, it's reasonable based on the physical Church-Turning thesis. The brain is a physical process, and according to the physical CT thesis, any function that is physically computable is Turing computable. Any ideas?

Comment: Not very clear... IF the mathematical function is computable, it can be formalized by a Turing machine, and thus the brain can be modeled by a TM.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes but the question doesn't specify whether the mathematical function is computable.